# Crank-set issue

Tags: crankset, 29er

I am having a crankset issue, I have tested by holding both brakes and moving the crank and pedals parallel and pushing down, with each 180 rotation,  the crank moves and thuds a little each side.

Anyone know how to sort this, is the crankset gone, bike is a XTC 29er.

Comment: It appears you have duplicated your own question... http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30863/crank-clank-bottom-bracket
Perhaps you could clarify & combine what you are trying to ask into one question

Comment: I got a failure on the android mobile stack, so created another on the web.. have deleted the other comment. thanks

Comment: It is easier to help you if you add a picture to clearly show the problem and the component types. Most likely, your crank set is good but you need to replace the bottom bracket. Please refer to: http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-standards-1

Comment: Thanks I have dropped it into the shop, will update the thread.

Comment: So the shop want me to replace the crank-set, I dont think I need to, as its fairly expensive, so I took the bike back.

Comment: I need to identify my BB, the crank set is a 9 speed truvativ, does anyone know if the following BB will fit my bike and crank set. http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ie/en/truvativ-howitzer-team-bottom-bracket/rp-prod40823

Answer (score 1):

In comments, I see you stated it is a Truvativ Crank...  The description of your problem sounds like it may be a couple problems.  If the bearings in the BB are worn out, it may make any kind of "clunky" feel.  But what it sounds like to me is it was ridden with crank pinch bolts loose for a bit and the BB/Crankarm interface might be worn down one way or the other.  It's entirely possible you may need to change out either.  You said you took it to a shop, may be worth getting a 2nd opinion if you weren't happy with their answer.  And this time, ask them to show you what's wrong.  As a mechanic, I was never against showing people, "Here's the wear, this is why we recommend changing this".  But be aware that at that point, the shop has invested time and money(in employee wages) in that repair.  Don't get the answer from the shop, then do the work yourself.  No shame in supporting your local shop when you can't diagnose a problem yourself.